# How do you @rpc _returns polymorphic types in spyne?

Tags: python, soap, spyne

**Edit**

Example,

```
class A(ComplexModel):
    Id = Unicode

class B(ComplexModel):
    __extends__ = A
    Name = Unicode

@rpc(String, _returns=A)
def hello(self, name):
    ret = B()
    B.Id = '123'
    B.Name = name
    return ret
```

How do you handle this behavior so it doesn't return an object of `A`?

---

How would I write the `spyne` decorators to correctly return more than one type? If, for example, _returns is set to `ZObj` then returning an `XAccount` (like in the code) doesn't do anything.

Can I write the `XAccount` object so that it extends `ZObj` and is a valid return type?

```
@rpc(String, _returns=(ZObj, XAccount))
def hello(self, name):
    acc = XAccount(
        user_name = name.upper(),
        first_name = name,
        last_name = 'last ' + name
    )
    return acc
```

Class examples....

```
class ZObj(ComplexModel):
    id = Unicode(pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}|\d+')

class Account(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'account'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String(256))
    first_name = Column(String(256))
    last_name = Column(String(256))


class XAccount(TableModel):
    __table__ = Account.__table__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting my previous answer as you apparently need polymorphism, not multiple return types.

So, There are two ways of doing polymorphism in Spyne: The Python way and the Spyne way.

Let:

```
class A(ComplexModel):
    i = Integer

class B(A):
    s = Unicode

class C(A):
    d = DateTime
```

The Python way uses duck typing to return values.

Let's define a generic class:

```
class GenericA(ComplexModel):
    i = Integer
    s = Unicode
    d = DateTime
```

and use it as return value of our sample service:

```
class SomeService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode(values=['A', 'B', 'C']), _returns=GenericA)
    def get_some_a(self, type_name):
        # (...)
```

This way, you get your data, but it's tagged as a `GenericA` object. If you don't care about this, you can create a class that has all types from all objects (assuming attributes with same names have the same type) and just be done with it. This is easy, stable and works today.

If that's not enough for your needs, you have to do the polymorphism the Spyne way. To do that, first set your return type to the base class:

```
class SomeService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode(values=['A', 'B', 'C']), _returns=A)
    def get_some_a(self, type_name):
        # (...)
```

and tag your output protocol to be polymorphic:

```
application = Application([SomeService], 'tns',
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=Soap11(polymorphic=True)
)
```

This requires at least Spyne-2.12.

Working example: https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/a1b3593f3754a9c8a6787c29ff50f591db89fd49/examples/xml/polymorphism.py

Comment: I only want to return a single value, but that value can be one of many types. If `XAccount` inherits from `ZObj`, and the `_returns` attribute is set to `ZObj` you can't return `XAccount`

Comment: Ah, you want polymorphism. That's implemented in 2.12, the beta is released but it's not on PyPI. I will announce once docs are out so you can try it.

Comment: Where/How would I use this in the `development` branch on github? What's the syntax? This functionality is imperative to our use case.

Comment: Please edit your question to ask about polymorphism and not multiple return types so I can answer.

Comment: I've updated the original question to reflect polymorphic returns via `rpc` decorator, @Burak-arslan

Answer (score 0):

Also, you don't need to do this:

```
class Account(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'account'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String(256))
    first_name = Column(String(256))
    last_name = Column(String(256))

class XAccount(TableModel):
    __table__ = Account.__table__
```

This works just as well:

```
from spyne import TTableModel

TableModel = TTableModel() # Think of this as Spyne's declarative_base

class Account(TableModel):
    __tablename__ = 'account'

    id = Integer(primary_key=True)
    user_name = Unicode(256)
    first_name = Unicode(256)
    last_name = Unicode(256)
```

where your table metadata is in `TableModel.Attributes.sqla_metadata`

Objects created this way are usable in both in SQLAlchemy queries and as Spyne types.