# How to properly get spyne polymorphic tagnames

Tags: python, xml, wsdl, spyne

Is there a way to get the specific class tag names from my spyne class definitions?

Given the case, my class hierarchy looks like this:

```
# models.py
class Vehicle(ComplexModel):
    ...

class Car(Vehicle):
    ...

class Bike(Vehicle):
    ...
```

Then I followed the instructions in the answers of this questions, cause their problem seems similar, to get the polymorphism working.

[how to implement abstract model in spyne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476642/how-to-implement-abstract-model-in-spyne)

[How do you @rpc _returns polymorphic types in spyne?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393692/how-do-you-rpc-returns-polymorphic-types-in-spyne)

Important code lines which were changed:

```
# start.py
application=Application(
    ...
    in_protocol=Soap11(...),
    out_protocol=Soap11(polymorphic=True)
)
```

So far, so good. After i did this, i've got the following response:

```
<!-- Response.xml -->
...
<Vehicle xsi:type="Car">
    ...
</Vehicle>
...
```

**So my question is:**

Can i get rid of the general class name `Vehicle` as the tag name and get the name of the specific class e.g. `Car` as tag name instead?

Therefore the response should be something like this:

```
<Car>
    ...
</Car>
```

I've seen some approaches with the `ctx.out_string" and some text replacement in this question:

[Remove the namespace from Spyne response variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832969/remove-the-namespace-from-spyne-response-variables)

Which I think probably can work out fine for me, but if there is a "conventional" way in the API, which I did not find yet, I would prefer to get known of it to use it instead.

Comment: This is how the SOAP polymorphism was implemented. Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: @BurakArslan Ok i wasn't familiar with that. I'll do a bit of research on that. No.

So what you are saying that there is no need for this kind of feature, cause xml interpreter like lxml should determine the `xsi:type` as the tagname when working with the xml. And ignore the general superclass as it is in the tagname, since the `xsi:type` is the specific type.

Comment: Now I see where you are coming from. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how XML polymorphism is supposed to work. `libxml2`'s schema validator (that you use through lxml) should interpret it properly.

OTOH, If you are sure you want distinction solely through tag names, have a look at the `<choice>` tag: http://w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-contentModel

Also see an article comparing the two approaches: http://ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-xsdchoice

You seem to have already figured out how to use polymorphism in Spyne. So here's how you use the `<choice>` tag: https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/57ef5c0db51cb194353c67d317990fe89bc4177d/spyne/test/interface/test_xml_schema.py#L51

Comment: Ok thanks. It's doing quite well, as you predicted it, but at the request execution i get this line repeatedly `DEBUG:spyne.protocol._base:Polymap miss cls switch: <class 'Vehicle'> => <class 'Car'>`. After getting into the code of `spyne.protocol._base.ProtocolMixin` it seems that in my case, `Vehicle` has no information about an inheriting class `Car` in `Vehicle.polymap`. How to fix this or should this be no concern to me, cause there no lacking functionality, when the polymap is not set?

Comment: This is not an error, it's just informing you that polymorphic class switch was performed without a `poly_map` lookup.

Comment: Ok, but I assume that this polymap should hold in my case the two subclasses, so that a proper lookup can happen. Is this correct? If it is, am i missing some kind of annotation to get this whole thing working?

Comment: Am i right, that if the subclasses are in the polymap, that the tagnames will switch from general `Vehicle` to specific `Car`? Also I think if this is the case, you would already have told me that, but just want to be clear with my question.

Comment: Believe me when I tell you that your use case has nothing to do with `poly_map` :) If you want actual tags, you need to use the `<choice>` tag like I showed you.

Comment: Ok but I can't use choice tags cause it would distinguish from my given interface, it's using `<sequence>`. Thanks anyway for responding so fast!